# How can validation loss increases than slowly decreases when overfitting?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, loss-functions, overfitting

I'm using CNN to do multi-regression jobs, but some wired results confuse me. Here's my training results curves:

[image]

As you can see, the training loss first decreases fastly and then converges, while validation loss starts to increase - indicates overfitting begins; However the validation loss starts to decreases again in a slow pace - which seems like the model still not converges. Can anyone explain this?

For references, I'm using MSE as loss with Adam as optimizer.

Comment: I think you figured it out, it looks like your model overfits in the first big dip, but then corrects this a little bit. Try decreasing the learning rate.

Comment: @user2974951 Thanks, I'm trying tuning LR and see what happens.

Comment: I've seen this called "double descent", you may find this paper interesting: https://mltheory.org/deep.pdf (warning huge PDF).

Comment: @DexGroves Wow, that's exactly what I need, thank you!